# Magento Multiwebsites switching

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

My website consists of 2 Languages english and french, as per the suggestion by the payment gateway i have created 2 websites. I have referred this link to 
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-snippet-for-switching-between-websites/ to switch between websites. It works but it is not navigating to exact page rather than it navigates to the base url.

Example. When i was in the page : www.example1.com/test for website1, As soon as i change the website, it navigates to www.example2.com. But i need to navigate to the url  www.example2.com/test

I dont know whether it is possible regarding this information. Need help regarding this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a small change in the refered link's code.

Change below line

```
<option <?php if(strstr($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), $default_store_path)):?>selected="selected"< ?php endif; ?> value="< ?php echo $default_store_path ?>">< ?php echo $website->getName()?></option>
```

to

```
<option <?php if(strstr($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), $default_store_path)):?>selected="selected"< ?php endif; ?> value="< ?php echo $default_store_path.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">< ?php echo $website->getName()?></option>
```